# Build library and Exe from the same MSBuild project?

Tags: .net, msbuild, f#, mono

My F# project consists of a .dll containing most of my program, a .dll of tests for NUnit, and a small .exe that loads the main library and runs the program.

How do I write a single MSBuild .fsproj file that can build all of these? MonoDevelop generates a project that produces a single output, and I can't find any documentation for MonoDevelop or the MSBuild format for producing multiple outputs for a single project.

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Solutions_and_Projects_explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.fsproj, .csproj, etc MSBuild files use Imports that are designed to produce a single Console Application, Windows Application or Class Library.

Use a solution file that references any number of separate MSBuild projects. A solution file is not an MSBuild file but MSBuild does translate a solution file into a temporary MSBuild file and builds it instead.